# Firefox Crash while recording remote stream from mobile (webRTC)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webrtc, mozilla

We are trying to implement one project where we are using webRTC to stream videos from mobile devices and a agent on desktop can monitor those streams.
Our Requirement says we should we able to record the stream video streamed from mobile devices.
Currently we are using RecordRTC solution to record the streamed video. its working fine if the stream is generating from pc . but if we try to record the stream generated from mobile(android/iOS) Firefox is crashing after 3-4 seconds.
this crash is not happening in chrome.
I tried hard to debug the problem behind the crash but i am unable to have any information from firefox browser.

But When I monitored the chrome://webrtc-internals/ it showed that the height and width of video is changing after 3-4 seconds.

Can this be the reason behind the firefox crash.

Please help us in resolving this issue. as according to requirements provided to us we have to use Firefox browser only.

Any suggestion will be of great help to us

Thanks

```
        var audioConfig = {};

        if (!isRecordOnlyAudio) {

            audioConfig.onAudioProcessStarted = function() {
                // invoke video recorder in this callback
                // to get maximum sync
                videoRecorder.startRecording();
            };
        }

        audioRecorder = RecordRTC(stream, audioConfig);

        if (!isRecordOnlyAudio) {
            // it is second parameter of the RecordRTC
            var videoConfig = {
                type: 'video'
            };
            videoRecorder = RecordRTC(stream, videoConfig);
        }

        audioRecorder.startRecording();
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a short sample of your code? Specifically, what is it your are doing when Firefox crashes? This is when you are playing the video recorded from the mobile device?

Comment: Hi I have added the code i am using to start recording the stream.No the crash is happening while recording the video stream

Comment: Have you checked Bugzilla to see if it has been reported? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=webrtc+crash

Comment: After debugging my code i got to know that crash is happening due to the change in resolution of streaming video.

Comment: Is there any fix to avoid this crash ? Our Requirement says user should be able to switch between portrait and landscape mode, sO FIXING THE RESOLUTION ON SMART PHONE SIDE IS NOT A SOLUTION